# Как реализовать запрос, группирующий количество записей в таблице за день на интервалы 5 минут - 1 час?

Tags: mysql

В таблице есть записи с полем datetime, нужно составить запрос (или несколько запросов), который бы группировал количество записей по временным интервалам от 5 минут до одного часа **за определенный день**, например в таблице есть 5 записей:

```
запись 1, datetime = 2018-08-21 00:00
запись 2, datetime = 2018-08-21 00:01
запись 3, datetime = 2018-08-21 00:05
запись 4, datetime = 2018-08-21 00:07
запись 5, datetime = 2018-08-21 00:09
```

выборка интервала 5 минут должна выглядеть так:

```
interval, count

00:00-00:04, 2
00:05-00:09, 3
00:10-00:14, 0
00:15-00:19, 0
..............
23:55-23:59, 0
```

выборка интервала 1 час:

```
интервал, количество записей

00:00-00:59, 5
01:00-01:59, 0
..............
23:00-23:59, 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Создали таблицу

```
create table `TableSource`(`datetime` datetime);
```

Внесли данные

```
insert into `TableSource` (`datetime`) values 
('2018-08-21 00:00:00'),
('2018-08-21 00:01:00'),
('2018-08-21 00:05:00'),
('2018-08-21 00:07:59'),
('2018-08-21 00:09:00');
```

Назначили день выборки

```
set @dt_selected = '2018-08-21';
```

Сделали запрос

```
select
  `seq`.`TimeFinish` `interval`,
  COALESCE(sum(`cou`),0) `count`
FROM
  (
  select 
    DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@dt_selected,INTERVAL t2.`h` HOUR),INTERVAL t1.`m` MINUTE) `TimeStart`,
    DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@dt_selected,INTERVAL t2.`h` HOUR),INTERVAL t1.`m` + 4 MINUTE) `TimeFinish`
  from 
    (select 0 `h`
    union select 1 
    union select 2 
    union select 3 
    union select 4
    union select 5
    union select 6
    union select 7
    union select 8
    union select 9
    union select 10
    union select 11
    union select 12
    union select 13
    union select 14
    union select 15
    union select 16
    union select 17
    union select 18
    union select 19
    union select 20
    union select 21
    union select 22
    union select 23
    ) t2
    cross join
    (select 0 `m` 
    union select 5 
    union select 10 
    union select 15
    union select 20
    union select 25
    union select 30 
    union select 35
    union select 40
    union select 45
    union select 50 
    union select 55
    ) t1
  ) `seq`
  left outer join 
  (
    select *, 1 `cou` from `TableSource`
  ) `TableSource`
  on `TableSource`.`datetime` between `seq`.`TimeStart` and `seq`.`TimeFinish`
group by 
  `seq`.`TimeStart`,
  `seq`.`TimeFinish`
ORDER BY 
  `seq`.`TimeStart`,
  `seq`.`TimeFinish`  
;
```

Полученные данные

```
interval    count
2018-08-21 00:04:00 2
2018-08-21 00:09:00 3
2018-08-21 00:14:00 0
2018-08-21 00:19:00 0
2018-08-21 00:24:00 0
2018-08-21 00:29:00 0
2018-08-21 00:34:00 0
2018-08-21 00:39:00 0
2018-08-21 00:44:00 0
2018-08-21 00:49:00 0
...
```

Для часового интервала выполняем

```
select
  `seq`.`TimeFinish` `interval`,
  COALESCE(sum(`cou`),0) `count`
FROM
  (
  select 
    DATE_ADD(@dt_selected,INTERVAL t2.`h` HOUR) `TimeStart`,
    DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@dt_selected,INTERVAL t2.`h` HOUR),INTERVAL 59 MINUTE) `TimeFinish`
  from 
    (select 0 `h`
    union select 1 
    union select 2 
    union select 3 
    union select 4
    union select 5
    union select 6
    union select 7
    union select 8
    union select 9
    union select 10
    union select 11
    union select 12
    union select 13
    union select 14
    union select 15
    union select 16
    union select 17
    union select 18
    union select 19
    union select 20
    union select 21
    union select 22
    union select 23
    ) t2
  ) `seq`
  left outer join 
  (
    select *, 1 `cou` from `TableSource`
  ) `TableSource`
  on `TableSource`.`datetime` between `seq`.`TimeStart` and `seq`.`TimeFinish`
group by 
  `seq`.`TimeStart`,
  `seq`.`TimeFinish`
ORDER BY 
  `seq`.`TimeStart`,
  `seq`.`TimeFinish`
```

Полученные данные

```
interval    count
2018-08-21 00:59:00 5
2018-08-21 01:59:00 0
2018-08-21 02:59:00 0
2018-08-21 03:59:00 0
2018-08-21 04:59:00 0
2018-08-21 05:59:00 0
2018-08-21 06:59:00 0
2018-08-21 07:59:00 0
2018-08-21 08:59:00 0
2018-08-21 09:59:00 0
2018-08-21 10:59:00 0
2018-08-21 11:59:00 0
2018-08-21 12:59:00 0
2018-08-21 13:59:00 0
2018-08-21 14:59:00 0
2018-08-21 15:59:00 0
2018-08-21 16:59:00 0
2018-08-21 17:59:00 0
2018-08-21 18:59:00 0
2018-08-21 19:59:00 0
2018-08-21 20:59:00 0
2018-08-21 21:59:00 0
2018-08-21 22:59:00 0
2018-08-21 23:59:00 0
```